# Можно ли инициализировать переменную в конструкторе не создавая экземпляр класса? PHP

Tags: php

Можно ли инициализировать переменную в конструкторе не создавая экземпляр класса. Например :

```
 class Class 
 { 

    private $value 


    public function __construct ($val){
     $this->value = $val
    }

    /**
    * @Route("/", methods="POST")
    */
    public function get(){
     echo $this->value;
    }
 }
```

Comment: как то интересно вы себе ООП представляете. не создавая экземпляр класса у вас в принципе отсутствует `$this`, так что ваше "например" вообще не понятно.

Comment: @teran, получил на руки странный код (работающий) в котором ситуация выглядит именно так. Пытаюсь понять как инициализируется в нём переменная `$value`. Хотел убедится у знающих людей не в этом участке кода ли "как-нибудь" это происходит. Буду искать дальше

Comment: @HegoJune, приведите весь код. текущий код - это просто описание класса.

Comment: `получил на руки странный код (работающий) в котором ситуация выглядит именно так. ` попробуйте это: `$c = new Class1(1); $c->__construct(2); var_dump($c->get());`. Кроме того, могут быть трейты, наследование. В конце концов, вы смотрите не тот файл. Используйте Reflection API для изучения объекта. Ну и __wakeup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Конструктор создаёт экземпляр класса, без его создания, невозможно вызвать конструктор. Смотрите в сторону статик переменных.

Comment: мне кажется или должно быть _"...невозможно вызвать метод"_, а не конструктор?

Comment: Почему? Переменная создаваться хочет, согласно вопросу, в конструкторе. Причём тут методы?

Comment: тогда меня несколько смущает, что у вас предложение начинается и заканчивается словом Конструктор. масло-масляное.

Comment: Тело конструктора вызывается в момент создание экземпляра класса. Соответственно, невозможно инициировать переменную в конструкторе, не создав экземпляр класса.